# Check if FirefoxOS application is updated or installed for the first time

Tags: firefox-os

Is it possible to obtain if installed application on the Firefox OS device is updated - there was already a previous version of the application ?

I would like to display a splash notification only for new users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no API for that and there is no real need for that either. What you might want to do is to check at lunchtime a few things.

You could use the localStorage api to store a value... let say a version number.

- If the value isn't present in the localStorage, then it means that the app is newly installed.
- If it's present and the value is equal to the one you expect... then you have the app already installed and "*initialized*"
- If it's present and the value is lower than the one you expect, then you have updated to a newer version of your app.

After the app is initialized, save the value in the localStorage or indexedDB. There's nothing magic about it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did it before but there are problems with testing. Every time I install newer app release (with Firefox WebIDE) - it gets new Application ID - so it also gets separated storage.
Will the ID not change when user'll update application from the store ?

Comment: As far as I know, when I install a new app with WebIDE, it replace the old ones and the local storage is the same. The only times when it saves the app as a different one is when I install the app from an other firefox release (different computer, different OS..) It will keep the old app and install a new one. But if the app is replaced as it should, the localStorage should be the same... that makes sense to me... otherwise people would have to backup every data somewhere before upgrading their app to the new one.